# Windows Phone - how to reuse animation defined in XAML for multiple dynamic objects

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a WP 8.1 app that creates multiple rectangles dynamically in the Page_Loaded event. I want to animate all those rectangles in the same way using one animation. It works great when I use the following code-behind:

```
foreach(...)
{
    (...)
    var rect = new Rectangle();
    var anim = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    var story = new Storyboard();

    story.Children.Add(anim);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(story, rect);
    (...)
}
```

I'd like to move the animation and storyboard definition to XAML resource and reuse it for all the dynamically created rectangles. Unfortunately when I call

```
App.Current.Resources["animationName"]
```

I always get the same instance of the object which can only be attached to one instance of the Rectangle. I think there could be two solutions (but I can't get any of them to work):

- Force the resources dictionary to return a new instance of the storyboard / animation every time
- Attach multiple dynamically created targets to one animation

Which option is better and how to approach them?

Comment: I can only suggest that moveing definition to XAML might not be a good idea at all as it would take hacking type of approach to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, the target is single so the only way is to clone the storyboards. Indeed you Storyboard is sealed
I have used this previously to clone and it works.

http://www.moonmile.net/blog/archives/4087

But in case you want to do without cloning on code behind you can add so DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames as you need in a items loop and

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(daukf, outerBorder);
```

instead the storyboard the keyframes.